# In Android Studio, I have some error about onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

I use the Navigation Drawer Activity and I use the webview in main activity.

1. I entered the app.
2. I go to second page from first(main) page.
3. when I press the back button, App is closed.

but I want to go the main page.

but it is correctly operated when I go to second page from third page(by pressing back button)

**(main page<->second page<->third page)**

**main page<->second page : error**

**second page<->third page : not error**

what can I do?

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (WebView01.canGoBack()) {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==false) {
            WebView01.goBack();
        }
    }
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    if((WebView01.canGoBack()==false)&&(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==false)){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: write your main page code ,which opens second page.

Comment: check your onResume method of mane page or anywhere finish() method is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure can you try this

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getview().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (WebView01.canGoBack()) {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==false) {
            WebView01.goBack();
        }
    }
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    if((WebView01.canGoBack()==false)&&(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)==false)){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by changing sequence of if-statement.
thanks.